# 1 include - 2 templates - 2 different results

Tags: channel-entries, embeds

I have an include / embed file that is being shared across two templates. However one template is displaying a result of the channel:entries tag in the embed whilst the other refuses to display a result.

I have tried updating the channel:entries tag and the second refuses to load content from any channel at all.

Below is the log information from template debugging:

Template 1:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1g8dw1npd1ysge1/Screenshot%202014-07-29%2017.50.53.png

Template 2:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/29redguruvjy5am/Screenshot%202014-07-29%2017.50.01.png

Comment: Add the [dynamic="no"](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic) parameter to the problematic template channel entries tag.

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed, completely slipped my mind about the dynamic="no" parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the same embed on different templates, I guess their URLs are different from each other. The results of `exp:channel:entries` tags are influenced by the URL.

If you need to bypass this influence, set the [`dynamic` parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic) to `no`.